# Can't find error in my regex

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to build a regex that is able to extract all Stackoverflow-like tags from a string. There is something wrong with my regex and I cant find what is:

```
s = 'call,me r c++ c# 132(list) 2345sdf;sdf_sfg? "adf-sdf aso.net?'
re.findall(r"[^,\s;\"\(\)]*[a-zA-Z0-9_\+\-\.#]*[a-zA-Z0-9_\+\-#]", s.lower())
```

I am getting

```
['call',
 'r',
 'c++',
 'c#',
 '132',
 'list',
 '2345sdf',
 'sdf_sfg',
 'adf-sdf',
 'aso.net']
```

So as you see the "me" after the comma is missing. I am also open to improvements on my regex.

EDIT: The pattern I want to match are valid SO tags, i.e. all characters in the set [a-zA-Z0-9_+-.#]. The rest of my expression is a hack to exclude the dot at the end of the sentence and someworkaround to eliminate the comma.

Comment: What is the pattern you want to match?

Comment: I ran your example, and it was fine on my python 2.7.3 Win 7.  Make sure your Python is up to date.  Also for weird things like embedded invisible characters or encoding issues with the string.

Comment: yes, you are right. I was excluding the 'me' in the next step of the preprocessing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>>> s = 'call,me r c++ c# 132(list) 2345sdf;sdf_sfg? "adf-sdf aso.net? foo. bar.'
>>> re.findall(r'\b\w[\w#+.-]*(?<!\.)', s)
['call', 'me', 'r', 'c++', 'c#', '132', 'list', '2345sdf', 'sdf_sfg', 'adf-sdf', 'aso.net', 'foo', 'bar']
```

I require tags to start after a word boundary with a word character. After that, I also capture as many word characters or those I explicitely listed (`#+.-`). So if you want to support another character, just add it to the character class.

The negative lookbehind at the end prevents tags from ending with a dot.

Comment: what can I do to exclude a dot at theend of the string?

Comment: @elyase: You can add a negative lookbehind at the end of the pattern: `(?<!\.$)`